# How do I set a PPPoE connection to redial?

Tags: pppoe

How to set auto redial in Ubuntu 11.10 like Windows XP where in Windows XP it asks you the number how many times want to re-dial if connection gets dropped where you set the number of re-dial like 10,20 or 100

Is there any option in Ubuntu I can set the number of redial if connection drops?
Please help my connection gets dropped every couple of hours or I have to get back to dumb Windows.... help me....

Answer (score 3):

`persist` in `/etc/ppp/peers/dls-provider` is important.

I also noticed that `maxfail 0` is very important too.
Specially if there is a problem with the line.
Without it pppd will give up after the 10th attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `persist` option in `/etc/ppp/options`, and it should keep trying forever.

Comment: and how do i do that ca you plz tell me in details exactly cause i m new to linux..

Comment: i got the option file now what do i change here to make it work

Comment: Add a new line saying "persist"

Comment: where do i add it ant specific line first or last  and only add single word persist ????

Comment: The order is unimportant

Comment: it didnt work for me after the connection drops the wired connection option disappears from the network manager so there is no chance to reconnect .. so i have to restart my computer to connect internet again plz help...

Comment: If you are losing the wired connection option from the NM menu, then there is something else going on here, too. Not sure what it is, though...